# how do i take a large amount of data and make them into a bunch of random lists

Tags: python, csv

I want to take a csv file filled with information of 5000 songs and turn them into 100 playslists of 50 songs, i can figure out how to make one but not 100 in one code.

```
path = "Top5000.csv"
def csvtopy(path) -> dict[str, any]:
    reviews=dict()
    with open(path) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
    playlist1 = []
    for i in range(50):
        for row in reader:
            playlist1.append(row[1])
    return playlist1

csvtopy(path)
```

Comment: Do you want every song to be in exactly one playlist? Or do you want 100 random playlists, each independently selected? (In the second case, some songs will be in several playlists and some will not be selected at all.)

Answer (score 0):

First load your songs titles from the csv into a list `allSongs` (I leave this to you as an exercice)

Then what you can do is make a loop that iterates 100 times and inside the loop, shuffle the list of all songs and take the first 50.

```
import random

allSongs = loadSongsFromCsv()  # implement this

playLists = []
for _ in range(100):
    random.shuffle(allSongs)  # shuffles the list in place
    playlists.append([allSongs[:50]])
```

after that playLists will be a list of 100 elements, each a list of 50 random songs